# Jump Table - assembly 8086

Tags: c, assembly, branch, jump-table

I've tried to make switch case like this:

```
 switch (si)
{
 case 1:
   printf( “Number One” );
   break;

case 2:
   printf( “Number Two” );
   break;

 case 3:
   printf( “Number Three” );
   break;

 case 4:
  printf( “Number Four” );
  break;
 }
```

In assembly 8086 with branch table/jump table:

```
enter code here
org 100h 

mov si,1 
mov bx,10
sub si,1
add si,si
mov bx,[bx+si]
jmp bx 

address:
dw 14 Case1
dw 17 Case2
dw 21 Case3
dw 24 Case4 

Case1: PRINTN "Number One"
jmp End

Case2: PRINTN "Number Two"   
jmp End

Case3: PRINTN "Number Three"
jmp End

Case4: PRINTN "Number Four"

End:
mov ah, 0
int 16h
ret
```

The PRINTN is like printf in C.

My code doesn't work and I don't know why...

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the magic numbers, 10,14,17,21,24?

Comment: *Can you plz fix my bugs?* - If you've found specific bugs and have tried to fix them, we can help.  Other than that, SO is not a code-debugging service.

Answer (score 1):

Example for to use a table and for to store some strings:

Address of the table itself = OFFSET JTab

```
JTab dw OFFSET Case1, OFFSET Case2, OFFSET Case3, OFFSET Case4
```

Addresses of some Strings with OFFSET of T1, T2, T3, T4 with lenght in len1, len2, ...

```
T1 db "Number One"
len1 = ($-T1)

T2 db "Number Two"
len2 = ($-T2)

T3 db "Number Three"
len3 = ($-T3)

T4 db "Number Four"
len4 = ($-T4)
```